# Calculate Column = Multiple Columns that could be empty

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column-formula

I have a calculated column that is set to the concatenation of several columns that could be empty...I have tried a few different options, but I keep getting an error.  Help would be greatly appreciated

```
=([Title-2])&" "&LayFirstName&" "&LayMiddleName&" "&LayLastName
```

any of the columns could be empty except LayFirstName and LayLastName

Comment: I tried the above formula with empty value and worked properly, so what's the error that you get in the above formula?

Comment: The formula works if all fields are filled, it there isn't anything in the field the calculation is null

Comment: what's your SharePoint version?

Comment: Office SharePoint 365

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ISBLANK` to check if the field is empty or not as te following:

```
=(Title)&" "&FirstName&" "&IF(ISBLANK([Middle]);"";[Middle])&" "&LastName
```

[image]

**Output**

[image]

---

**By the way,** I tried the above formula in SharePoint 2013 and I get the same result
[image]

Comment: The formula contains a syntax error or is not supported.

Comment: do you replaced your column , please paste your current formula after update

Comment: The single line of text is selected, but I don't know why I keep getting that error...

Comment: It's not a single line of text column it's calculated column and and this type is **The data type returned from this formula of the calculated column.**

Comment: Ok, thank you so much, Title-2 column needed to be encased in the []

Comment: Glad to hear it working, in case the above answers helped you. please don't forget to mark it as an answer,  also please take a tour at https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour to get informed badge. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this - change the name of the columns accordingly:

```
 =CONCATENATE(IF(ISBLANK(Title)," ",Title)," ",fn," ",IF(ISBLANK(mn)," ",mn)," ",ln)
```

[image]

Comment: I thought it worked, but I get NULL in the field still if the Title or Middle Name is empty

Comment: is there an ISNULL function

Comment: I tested this again and it is working fine for me.  you might want to ensure that the field names provided are correct. If there are spaces in the field name use [My Field Name].  I added a screenshot

Comment: This is the coding I end up having to use...I do not understand why the other functions did not work...but now it does...=CONCATENATE(IF(ISERROR([Title-2]),"",[Title-2])," ",LayFirstName," ",IF(ISERROR(LayMiddleName)," ",LayMiddleName),"",LayLastName)

Comment: Just trying replacing ISERROR with ISBLANK.  What error you get?